# Java gui, Client issue when trying to convert into gui

Tags: java, user-interface, io

I have made a Client/Server programme in java, I have gotten it to work using the cmd perfectly as i want, now i am trying to convert the client side of the code into GUI, however i am having trouble with printing the client msg and reading the client input from the text fields and the server msg, here is what I have done so far, i get no errors when compiling  but the gui it self doesn't run, any help is appreciated.
Here is the Client code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

    public class TcpClient
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                new TcpClient().start();
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Major Error" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void start() throws IOException
        {
            JFrame build = new JFrame("Client");
            JTextField serv = new JTextField();
            JTextField clie = new JTextField();
            build.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            serv.setBounds(50,210,300,50);
            build.add(serv);

            clie.setBounds(350,210,300,50);
            build.add(clie);
        //=====================================================================
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            InetAddress hostA = null;
            PrintWriter clientOutput = null;
            BufferedReader clientInput = null;
            BufferedReader standardInput = null;        
            try
            {

                hostA = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                clientSocket = new Socket(hostA.getHostName(), 5600);
                clientInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                clientOutput = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                standardInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String serverMsg, clientMsg;

                //read from a socket and respond back to server
                while((serverMsg = clientInput.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    serv.setText("Server Saying - " + serverMsg);
                    if(serverMsg.equals("exit"))
                        break;

                    clientMsg = standardInput.readLine();
                    if(clientMsg != null)
                    {   
                        clie.setText("Client Saying - " + clientMsg);
                        clientOutput.println(clientMsg);
                    }
               }

         }

    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {

        System.exit(1);
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {

        System.exit(1);
    }   

    finally
    {
        //clean up time
        clientOutput.close();
        clientInput.close();
        standardInput.close();
        clientSocket.close();

    }       
        //=====================================================================
        build.setLayout(null);
        build.setSize(700,600);
        build.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        build.setVisible(true);
        build.setResizable(false);
        }
}
```

Comment: You're running the socket and the GUI on the same tread. The `while((serverMsg = clientInput.readLine()) != null)` loop is blocking the thread which means that  `build.setVisible(true);` won't be called until the server is closed. You should learn about [multithreading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency) and the [EDT thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you should study multithreading and especially the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

What is happening right now is that your code and your GUI and preventing each other from working properly. By having your GUI run on the EDT your application can run without holding back the GUI. When the application has changes to report that are relevant for your GUI you can just inform the EDT when the time comes.